# On a curious map from the complex projective plane into $S^5$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, embeddings

I have heavily edited the post (including the title), based on a comment by @GregoryArone that my map $f$ is not injective. In an earlier version of this post, I had thought to have constructed a smooth map from $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ into $S^5$, which I thought was a topological embedding. Removing a point from $S^5$ and using stereographic projection, I had thought to have found a topological embedding of $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ inside $S^5$, but I was mistaken. My map was actually not injective. However, this raised an interesting question.

Question set 1: does there exist a topological embedding of $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ inside $\mathbb{R}^5$? Or is there maybe a topological obstruction to that?

In the second part of this post, I will describe a smooth map $f$ from $\mathrm{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ into $S^5$ which is a double cover that is branched over a real slice of $\mathrm{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$, with respect to a real structure $\sigma$ on $\mathrm{P}^2$, defined by
$$ \sigma([z_0:z_1:z_2]) = [\bar{z}_2:-\bar{z}_1:\bar{z}_0].$$
Note that $\sigma$ is the real structure which is induced by the "antipodal map" $j$ on $P^1_\mathbb{C}$, defined by
$$j([u_0:u_1]) = [-\bar{u}_1:\bar{u}_0].$$

I will now describe how the map $f$ is defined. First, define the map $g: \mathrm{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \times \mathrm{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathrm{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$:
$$ ([u_0:u_1], [v_0:v_1]) \mapsto [2u_0v_0: u_0 v_1 + u_1 v_0: 2u_1v_1].$$ Then $g$ is holomorphic and onto. The symmetric group $S_2$ acts on the domain of $g$ by permuting the two factors, namely the $u$-point with the $v$-point, so to speak. The fibers of $g$ are actually the $S_2$ orbits in the domain of $g$.

The (extended) Hopf map $h$ is a smooth map from $\mathbb{C}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}^3$, defined by

$$h(u_0,u_1) = \left( 2 \operatorname{Re}(u_0 \bar{u}_1), 2 \operatorname{Im}(u_0 \bar{u}_1), |u_0|^2 - |u_1|^2 \right).$$

The group $U(1)$ acts on the domain of $h$ by scalar multiplication, and the fibers of $h$ are the $U(1)$-orbits in the domain of $h$.

Then the map
$$ h \times h: \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3$$
followed by the map
$\operatorname{Sym}: \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \to S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ which maps $(x,y)$ to $x \odot y$, gives a map
$$k: \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^2 \to S^2(\mathbb{R}^3),$$
where $k = \operatorname{Sym} \circ (h \times h)$. In turn, $k$ induces a smooth map
$$\tilde{k}: \mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \times \mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \to S^5,$$
where the latter is the unit sphere in $S^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \simeq \mathbb{R}^6$. Indeed, $k$ maps
$$(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}) \times (\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}) \to S^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \},$$
and the latter maps onto $S^5$ by the normalization map, with respect to the inner product on $S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ induced by the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that this composed map
$$(\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}) \times (\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}) \to S^5$$
is invariant under rescaling each of the $2$ factors of its domain individually, and so induce a smooth map which we are denoting by $\tilde{k}$, from $\mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \times \mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ into $S^5$.

The fibers of $\tilde{k}$ are actually of the form
$$(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}), (j\mathbf{u}, j\mathbf{v}), (\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u}), (j\mathbf{v}, j\mathbf{u})$$
where $\mathbf{u} = [u_0:u_1]$, $\mathbf{v} = [v_0:v_1]$ are points on $\mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ and $j$ is the "antipodal map" which was previously defined. Note that $h(j\mathbf{u}) = -h(\mathbf{u})$.

We are now ready to define our map
$$f: \mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C} \to S^5.$$
Given a point $p \in \mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$, let $w \in g^{-1}(p)$ and define
$$f(p) = \tilde{k}(w).$$

Then $f$ is a well defined smooth map from $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ into $S^5$, which is invariant under the real structure $\sigma$, which was previously defined. In fact, $f$ is a double cover onto its image (a codimension $1$ subset of $S^5$) which is branched over the real slice of $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $\sigma$. A generic fiber of $f$ is a pair of $\sigma$-conjugate points in $\mathrm{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$.

Note that if we think of the coordinates of $S^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ as the components of a real $3$-by-$3$ symmetric matrix $A$, then it is not too difficult to see that $\tilde{k}$ maps $\mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C} \times \mathrm{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ into the real quasi-affine variety

$$V = \{ \det(A) = 0 \} \cap \{ \operatorname{tr}(A^2) = 1 \} \cap 
\{ \operatorname{tr}(A)^2 \leq 1 \}.$$

In other words, these conditions ensure that the eigenvalues of $A$, which must be real, are of the form: $0$, $\lambda$, $\mu$ with $\lambda \mu \leq 0$ and $\lambda^2 + \mu^2 = 1$ (note that $\lambda$, or $\mu$, may be $0$).

Hence the image of $f$ is contained in $V$.

Question 2: is the image of $f$ equal to $V$? **Edit:** I think the image of $f$ is indeed $V$. Just note that it suffices to diagonalize $A$, and show that a diagonal matrix having $0$, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ as (real) eigenvalues and satisfying the previous conditions is in the image of $f$. And this is straightforward.

Finally, I suspect I am just rediscovering that the complex projective plane modulo complex conjugation is the $4$-sphere, except that instead of complex conjugation, I am using a different real structure. Indeed, this "folklore" result is proved and discussed for instance in

- Michael Atiyah, Jurgen Berndt, *Projective planes, Severi varieties and spheres*, Surveys in Differential Geometry VIII, Papers in Honor of Calabi, Lawson, Siu and Uhlenbeck, International Press (2003) pp.1-27. doi:[10.4310/SDG.2003.v8.n1.a1](https://doi.org/10.4310/SDG.2003.v8.n1.a1),
  arXiv:[math/0206135](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206135).

Question 3: is the image of $f$ diffeomorphic to $S^4$? If so, then it would provide yet another proof of the previous folklore result. A related question is whether or not $V$ is diffeomorphic to $S^4$.
**Edit:** I think I can build a diffeomorphism from $S^4$ onto $V$. Think of $S^4$ as the set
$$W = \{ B \,|\, \text{$B$ real symmetric $3$-by-$3$, } \operatorname{tr}(B) = 0 \text{ and } \operatorname{tr}(B^2) = 1 \}.$$
It is not too difficult to see that $W$ is diffeomorphic to $S^4$. Define a map from $W$ into $V$, by
$$ B \mapsto \frac{B - \lambda_2(B) I}{\lVert B - \lambda_2(B)I \rVert},$$
where $\lambda_1(B) \leq \lambda_2(B) \leq \lambda_3(B)$ are the $3$ eigenvalues of $B$. I think that this map is perhaps a diffeomorphism from $W$ onto $V$. However, I am not sure about its smoothness when $2$ eigenvalues of $B$ collide. Can someone comment on that please?

Comment: Oh wow that would be cool, it would show that a codimension 1 embedding into Euclidean space doesn’t imply trivial normal bundle which also gives lots of other things like an embedding with no normal bundle - really shows how badly behaved topological manifolds are.

Comment: Are you sure about the identification of Sym$^2(\mathbb R^3)$ with $\mathbb R^6$? Looks suspicious to me, but maybe I am confused. Sym$^2(\mathbb R^2) \cong \mathbb R^4$, but I don't think it works in any other dimension.

Comment: @GregoryArone, this is like calculating the dimension of the space of homogeneous quadratic polynomials in $3$ (real) variables. Maybe it is the notation which is confusing? By $\operatorname{Sym}^2V$ I mean the symmetric tensor of $V$ with itself.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your notation, apologies.

Comment: I still don't think that the map ${\mathrm P}^2_{\mathbb C}\to S^5$ is injective. I may be confused again, but it seems that the map $P^1_{\mathbb C}\times P^1_{\mathbb C} \to \mbox{Sym}^2(\mathbb R^3)$ can be identified with the map $S^2\times S^2\to \mathbb R^6$ that sends $((x, y, z), (x', y', z'))$ to $(xx', yy', zz', xy'+x'y, xz'+x'z, yz'+y'z)$. This map identifies $(\bar u, \bar v)$ with $(-\bar u, -\bar v)$ and not just with $(\bar v, \bar u)$.

Comment: I strongly suspect that there is a cohomological obstruction to the existence of a topological embedding ${\mathbb P}^2_{\mathbb C} \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^5$ and even into $\mathbb R^6$. More specifically, I suspect that the van Kampen obstruction is not zero.

Comment: @GregoryArone, thank you so much for your comments! I have edited my post heavily in light of your comment that my map $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @GregoryArone: There is a topological obstruction to locally flat embedding of a closed 4-manifold X in $R^5$ or $R^6$. In either case, you would conclude that X is spin, and that the signature of X is 0. You can have a non-locally flat embedding in $R^6$ with a single non-flat point if X is spin; for instance a K3 surface has such an embedding.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Sorry, are you saying that there definitely is a non-flat embedding of $\mathbb CP^2$ into $\mathbb R^6$, or only that there might be?

Comment: If your statement at the first paragraph that $f$ is smooth is valid then I presume we are allowed to talk about normal bundle. By composing with the standard embedding in to 6-dimensional Eclidean space, by Pontrjagin-Thom theory up to isotopy your are looking at $\pi_6MO(2)$. If you knew that your normal bundle has a complex structure then you will be looking at $\pi_6MU(1)\simeq\pi_6CP^\infty\simeq 0$ which immediately implies all such embeddings are isotopic. I am not sure if this is any useful ?!

Comment: @GregoryArone I certainly don't know a non-flat (topological) embedding of $CP^2$ in $R^6$. It is conceivable to me that there could be such an embedding, but it seems hard to find one. One might start by figuring out what the singularities would look like. I don't know how to rule out an embedding into $R^5$. The only sensible statement I know along these lines is that an embedding into $R^5$ couldn't have isolated singular points. This is an old theorem of Kirby about codimension one embeddings.

Comment: @user51223 You only get a normal bundle if $f$ is an immersion; smoothness would not suffice.

Comment: @user51223 If there is a normal bundle it is much simpler, the normal bundle would be rank 1 and the only rank 1 bundles over $\mathbb{C}P2$ are trivial which would imply that all Chern classes of the space vanish, which they do not.

Comment: @user51223 An example of a smooth map that is an embedding but not an immersion is $(t^2,t^3)$. With real coordinates it has a corner, so it is not an immersion, but it is topologically conjugate to the standard embedding. But with complex coordinates, it is not "locally flat"; that is, the submanifold is the cone on a circle, but it is a knotted circle, so it cannot be even topologically conjugate to the standard embedding.

Comment: In light of all the corrections/edits it might be good to highlight the actual question here. I take it the question is now: is there a topological embedding of CP2 into S5?

Comment: @SamHopkins, I know, I agree with you :). I was just thinking to clean up my post, and edit it carefully.

Comment: @SamHopkins Good point. Anyone who wants an easier version might start by checking whether there's a topological (again, no flatness/smoothness assumptions) of $RP^2$ in $R^3$. I'm betting that there isn't.

Comment: @SamHopkins and everybody, I have just edited my post!

Comment: @Ben Wieland thanks. I had forgotten about the derivative that should be full rank.

Comment: In Q1 are you sure you don't mean to ask about an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$ (since $S^5\subseteq \mathbb{R}^6$)? Of course, the answer below shows there is no embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$, hence none into $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: @SamHopkins, well I was thinking if the image misses a point on $S^5$, then it would be an embedding inside $\mathbb{R}^5$. But in any case, as you say, Gregory Arone's answer shows there is no embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think I can prove the following

**Claim** There is no topological embedding of $\mathbb CP^2$ into $\mathbb R^6$.

The proof uses the van Kampen obstruction. Let me review the idea. Suppose there is a topological embedding $f\colon \mathbb CP^2\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^6$. Then $f$ induces a $\Sigma_2$-equivariant map of deleted squares
$$
f^2_\Delta\colon \mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2 \to \mathbb R^6\times \mathbb R^6\setminus \mathbb R^6.
$$
Let $\widetilde S^5$ denote the $5$-dimensional sphere with the antipodal action of $\Sigma_2$. There is a $\Sigma_2$-equivariant map (in fact a homotopy equivalence)
$$
\mathbb R^6\times \mathbb R^6\setminus \mathbb R^6 \xrightarrow{\simeq} \widetilde S^5.
$$
It follows that a topological embedding $f$ would induce a $\Sigma_2$-eqivariant map
$$
\mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2 \to \widetilde S^5.
$$
So to prove that there is no topological embedding, it is enough to prove that there is no such map. An equivariant map like this is essentially the same things as a nowhere vanishing section of the vector bundle
$$
(\mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2)\times_{\Sigma_2} {\widehat {\mathbb R}}^6 \to (\mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2)_{\Sigma_2}.
$$
Here $\widehat {\mathbb R}^6$ is the $6$-dimensional sign representation of $\Sigma_2$. The Euler class of this vector bundle is an obstruction to the existence of a section, and therefore to the existence of a topological embedding. This is the van Kampen obstruction.

It remains to prove that the Euler  class is non-zero. All cohomology groups will be taken with mod 2 coefficients. The Euler class is an element of $H^6\left((\mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2)_{\Sigma_2}\right)$. The cohomology ring of $\left(\mathbb CP^2\times \mathbb CP^2\setminus \mathbb CP^2\right)_{\Sigma_2}$ was calculated in the following paper

Samuel Feder, *The reduced symmetric product of projective spaces and the generalized Whitney theorem*, Illinois J. Math. 16 (1972), 323–329  https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1256052288

If I am parsing the result of this paper correctly, the cohomology ring is generated by two elements $u_1, x_2$, subject to just the relations $x_2^3=0$ and $u_1^3=u_1x_2$. It follows that as a vector space, the cohomology has following basis
$$
1, u_1, u_1^2, x_2, u_1x_2=u_1^3, u_1^2x_2=u_1^4, x_2^2, u_1x_2^2=u_1^5, u_1^2x_2^2=u_1^6.
$$
The main point is that $u_1^6\ne 0$. Clearly $u_1$ is the Euler class of the $1$-dimensional sign representation, so $u_1^6$ is the Euler class of the $6$-dimensional sign representation.

Comment: Awesome answer. I just have a question please. Why is the Euler class of the $1$-dimensional sign representation equal to $u_1$? In particular, why is it nonzero? I forgot how to calculate Euler classes.

Comment: If $X$ is any simply connected space with a free action of $\Sigma_2$ then the (mod $2$) Euler class of the canonical line bundle over $X/_{\Sigma_2}$ is non-zero. To see this, think of the canonical map $X/_{\Sigma_2}\to \mathbb RP^\infty$. This map is induced by taking $\Sigma_2$ orbits of a $\Sigma_2$-equivariant map $X\to S^{\infty}$. By covering space theory the induced map of orbits is an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and therefore it is an isomorphism on $H^1$. The Euler class is the image of the generator of $H^1(\mathbb RP^\infty; \mathbb F_2)$.